# Creating Packages of ros-<distro>-package_name type

Tags: ros, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Folks,

How do I convert my catking workspace in the equivalent of a, for instance, ros-indigo-openni2_camera type? By that I mean, how can I distribute my packages to other computers without having to share my code?

I want to have the same effect as when I do, for instance, sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-openni2-launch on my terminal.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246981/creating-packages-of-ros-%3Cdistro%3E-package_name-type/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2016-11-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do catkin_make --install. This will create an install directory and put all your package binaries, launch files and config files in /lib and /share respectively. You can zip this install folder and unzip it in a different catkin workspace. Make sure you copy /lib into /opt/ros/lib and /share to /opt/ros/share.

---

Originally posted by [ajain](https://answers.ros.org/users/18985/ajain/) with karma: 281 on 2016-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2016-11-01**:
seems like the "--" does not go before "install." What if I have personal ".txt" files I need to access? Will they also be installed inside the "install" folder?

**Comment by [ajain](https://answers.ros.org/users/18985/ajain/) on 2016-11-02**:
Yes. You can install rules to copy any directory into your /share directory of install like this -

```
install(DIRECTORY launch/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/launch)
```

This will copy all files inside /launch directory of your package to /share/<pkg_name>/launch .

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can create debs (debain packages) for your package by [releasing it to the ROS build farm with bloom](http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/FirstTimeRelease).

This means that your source code will be public, and the ROS build farm will download your source code, build binary packages, and make them available through apt on the ROS apt repository.

If you want to keep your source code private you'll need to run your own build server and host your own apt repository.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-11-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2016-11-01**:
Can I create the .deb s without putting it in github, just locally? Then send it to someone through email, or something. You know what I mean?

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-11-02**:
@ahendrix, better answer than the accepted one since OP asks for deb packages installed from apt repos.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-11-02**:
@Pototo: bloom has a few assumptions about working with repositories on github, but you could just as easily use local git repositories on your machine and then build the deb locally.

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2016-11-02**:
I see. I'll try the local repositories